# website not working after moving from local to the server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, server

am using codeigniter 2.2 and my os is ubuntu 14.04 . I have developed a website using codeigniter on my localhost. it was working fine.

now i have moved the site to the real server http://hotlunchorders.com/. i am getting the error.

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@hotlunchorders.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

**my .htaccess file**

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

**errorlog file in server**

```
    [Thu Jun 04 08:00:35 2015] [error] [client 67.213.90.137] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/hotlunchorders/public_html/index.php" is writeable by group
    [Thu Jun 04 08:00:35 2015] [error] [client 67.213.90.137] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/hotlunchorders/public_html/index.php" is writeable by group
    [Thu Jun 04 07:59:57 2015] [error] [client 67.213.90.137] File does not exist: /home/hotlunchorders/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://hotlunchorders.com/beta/index.php/profile/index
    [Thu Jun 04 07:59:57 2015] [error] [client 67.213.90.137] File does not exist: /home/hotlunchorders/public_html/beta/assets/css/global-style-color-icon.css, referer: http://hotlunchorders.com/beta/index.php/profile/index
    [Thu Jun 04 07:59:54 2015] [error] [client 67.213.90.137] File does not exist: /home/hotlunchorders/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://hotlunchorders.com/beta/index.php/home/index
    [Thu Jun 04 07:59:54 2015] [error] [client 67.213.90.137] File does not exist: /home/hotlunchorders/public_html/beta/assets/css/global-style-color-icon.css, referer: http://hotlunchorders.com/beta/index.php/home/index
    [Thu Jun 04 07:59:49 2015] [error] [client 67.213.90.137] File does not exist: /home/hotlunchorders/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://hotlunchorders.com/beta/index.php/order/step4/cod
    [Thu Jun 04 07:59:49 2015] [error] [client 67.213.90.137] File does not exist: /home/hotlunchorders/public_html/beta/assets/css/global-style-color-icon.css, referer: http://hotlunchorders.com/beta/index.php/order/step4/cod
    [Thu Jun 04 07:59:42 2015] [error] [client 67.213.90.137] File does not exist: /home/hotlunchorders/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://hotlunchorders.com/beta/index.php/order/step3
    [Thu Jun 04 07:59:42 2015] [error] [client 67.213.90.137] File does not exist: /home/hotlunchorders/public_html/beta/assets/css/global-style-color-icon.css, referer: http://hotlunchorders.com/beta/index.php/order/step3
    [Thu Jun 04 07:59:30 2015] [error] [client 67.213.90.137] File does not exist: /home/hotlunchorders/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://hotlunchorders.com/beta/index.php/order/step2
    [Thu Jun 04 07:59:30 2015] [error] [client 67.213.90.137] File does not exist: /home/hotlunchorders/public_html/beta/assets/css/global-style-color-icon.css, referer: http://hotlunchorders.com/beta/index.php/order/step2
    [Thu Jun 04 07:59:26 2015] [error] [client 67.213.90.137] File does not exist: /home/hotlunchorders/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://hotlunchorders.com/beta/index.php/order/step1
    [Thu Jun 04 07:59:26 2015] [error] [client 67.213.90.137] File does not exist: /home/hotlunchorders/public_html/beta/assets/css/global-style-color-icon.css, referer: http://hotlunchorders.com/beta/index.php/order/step1
    [Thu Jun 04 07:58:07 2015] [error] [client 67.213.90.137] File does not exist: /home/hotlunchorders/public_html/500.shtml
    [Thu Jun 04 07:58:07 2015] [error] [client 67.213.90.137] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/hotlunchorders/public_html/index.php" is writeable by group
    [Thu Jun 04 07:58:05 2015] [error] [client 67.213.90.137] File does not exist: /home/hotlunchorders/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://hotlunchorders.com/beta/index.php/profile/index
```

Can someone help me to fix this problem. tnx.

Comment: check if the apache configuration allow overrides or has mod_rewrite enabled.

Comment: Check if you don't have messed up UPPER and lower case in files/functions/classes/etc names

Comment: Please give 755 file permission for CI files.

Comment: file permission is 755 and mod_rewrite is also enabled. still the same probleum

Comment: @SathyaBaman see the answer, have you checked the filepaths?

Comment: @sitilge tnx filepaths are perfect. it didn't help. But i re installed the codeigniter and added the files one by one. now it works.

Comment: So close the answer if it is solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Points to look at:

1. Is `rewrite` module enabled? Enable by `sudo a2enmod rewrite`.
2. Are paths correct? [Linux is case sensitive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60276/why-is-the-terminal-case-sensitive).
3. *is writeable by group* may point out the permission problems. Try changing permission set to `sudo chmod 0750` respective files and directories.